# Redirect stdout/stderr of a script to a file along with command itself and the result stderr of time command

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, time, stderr

My chain command: `mkdir mydir; mv myscript.py mydir/; python3 mydir/myscript.py;`

1. Redirect `stdout` and `stderr` of `myscript.py` to `log.txt`.

```sh
$ mkdir mydir; mv myscript.py mydir/; python3 mydir/myscript.py 2>&1 | tee log.txt
$ cat log.txt
stdout and stderr are shown here.
```

2. Insert the chain command to the beginning of `log.txt`.

```sh
$ echo 'mkdir mydir; mv myscript.py mydir/; python3 mydir/myscript.py 2>&1' | tee log.txt | bash >> log.txt
$ cat log.txt
mkdir mydir; mv myscript.py mydir/; python3 mydir/myscript.py 2>&1
stdout and stderr are shown here.
```

3. Time the command

```sh
$ (time python3 mydir/myscript.py) 2> log.txt
$ cat log.txt

real    0m0,302s
user    0m0,003s
sys 0m0,001s
```

My question is how to concatenate 3 items above so the `log.txt` looks like

```sh
mkdir mydir; mv myscript.py mydir/; python3 mydir/myscript.py 2>&1
stdout and stderr are shown here.

real    0m0,302s
user    0m0,003s
sys 0m0,001s
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries and errors, I think the following code is working.

```sh
(time echo 'mkdir mydir; mv myscript.py mydir/; python3 mydir/myscript.py 2>&1' | tee log.txt | bash >> log.txt) 2>> log.txt
```